# How to boost up my Steam download speed?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

Well, there's a huge difference of speed I get while downloading from the Internet and downloading from Steam.

I get like ups and downs speed, which actually most of the time is stuck at 0 bytes/ sec. It suddenly rises up and goes like 90kbps. My peak download rate remains at 300kbps, that too for one second.

How do I boost up my speed? I'm from India and I kept the download server location at India, that didn't help. I tried UK, London - and it's giving me the same speed.

Any tweaks for this noob?

Comment: There really isn't much you can do; Steam's content servers are most likely fixed, and you're stuck with the speed you've got.

Comment: I seem to recall some settings that told steam how fast your internet connection was, and what geographic area to download from. I don't know where you are, but perhaps you can tweak those to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why this was closed.  Steam is most certainly on-topic.  Any of the close voters want to weigh in?

Comment: @fbueckert Because in all honesty, this sounds more like a problem with a firewall or other program blocking steam, then steam itself. Which means this question would be offtopic. The only awnser on this question isn't even about gaming.

Comment: @Lyrion *If* networking is the actual underlying problem, then diagnosing that it is indeed the problem is on-topic. Solving it is also on topic if the solution is trivial, such as "open port NNN in your firewall", because trivial steps to get gaming software working is on topic. If the solution is complex, then diagnosing it is still on-topic, but the complex networking issue is off topic and a good answer will refer the user to more information, such as on SuperUser.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes ofcourse, solving network issues is the task of arqade...

Comment: I just want to clearly clarify, that a few years ago I went on a holiday to India myself, and went through the exact same gruesome problem. 5GB games would take over 3 days download. Steam should really increase the download speed in MANY areas in the world that have similar demands to US and the UK. Steam is really restricting itself by doing so.

Answer (score 3):

If there are any special network configurations you have to set on your computer, you should ask your internet service provider.

Otherwise, in all likelihood, you will just have to pay more for a faster internet connection (assuming you have a choice and your local infrastructure supports it).

Answer (score 1):

Other than checking this page with settings under Steam->Settings:

[image]

There isn't much that you can do.

Comment: HA - another Austrian

Comment: Actually i'm romanian but i didn't bothered to change the country since i get the same speed :)